# Similar way to make an alert msg for blank spot?

Tags: javascript

If no number is introduced then a message should be displayed asking the user to input at least one number.

I'd like to know if there's another way to do it? If I enter a value for `b(num2)` or `c(num3)` and I won't input `a(num1)` I get that alert popup from end

**Javascript**

```
function max(){
    var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    var c=parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);
        if(a>b && a>c){
            alert(num1.value);
            }else if(b>a && b>c){
            alert(num2.value);
            }else if(c>a && c>b){
                alert(num3.value);
            }else if(a>b && a>c){
                alert(num1.value);
            }else if(a>b){
                alert(num1.value);
            }else if(a>c){
                alert(num1.value);
                return;
            }else if(b>a){
                alert(num2.value);
            }else if(b>c){
                alert(num2.value);
            }else if(c>a){
                alert(num3.value);
            }else if(c>b){
                alert(num3.value);
            }else if(a){
                alert(num1.value);
            }else if(b){
                alert(num2.value);
            }else if(c){
                alert(num3.value);
            }

        if (document.getElementById("num1").value == "") {
                alert("Input at least one number");
            }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="num1" >a </br><br>
<input type="text" id="num2" >b </br><br>
<input type="text" id="num3" >c </br><br>
<button onclick="max()">"Click me !</button>
```

Comment: so you have three input fields , if user doesnt entered anything clicking on button you need to show an alert please enter a number. Also once clicked on button you need to show the max value. Is this is the requirement

Comment: i wanted to popup that alert only when is no number entered in each textboxes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max might help you getting a cleaner code

Comment: @DanielKrom ty !

Answer (score 2):

```js
function max(){
var a=parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
var b=parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
var c=parseInt(document.getElementById("num3").value);

//exclude NaNs
nbs = [a,b,c].filter(nb => !isNaN(nb));

  if (isNaN(a) && isNaN(b) && isNaN(c)) {
    alert("Input at least one number");
  }
  else {
    console.log(Math.max(...nbs));
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1" >a </br><br>
<input type="text" id="num2" >b </br><br>
<input type="text" id="num3" >c </br><br>
<button onclick="max()">"Click me !</button>
```

Comment: you're awesome . ty 4 helping ^^

Comment: `isNaN(a) && isNaN(b) && isNaN(c)` I think it should be `||` and not `&&`, at least when the message is `Input at least one number` and not "All numbers"

Comment: Using `||` you'd have to input all three numbers to avoid the alert while the message is, as you said yourself, "Input `at least one` number"

Answer (score 0):

@Leny Lestter, you can use below jquery function

```
var empty = 0;
      $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
         if (this.value == "") {
             alert(' empty input' +$(this).attr("id"))
         } 
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will solve your issue.

```js
function max(){
  // checking rhe three fields have value
  var inputs = $("body :input:not(:checkbox):not(:button)");
  var emptyfields = inputs.filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0
     }).length == 0;
  if(emptyfields){
    // fields are not empty you can write code here
  }else{
    alert("Input fields can't be empty")
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="num1" >a </br><br>
<input type="text" id="num2" >b </br><br>
<input type="text" id="num3" >c </br><br>
<button onclick="max()">"Click me !</button>
```